# multiple values for each dynamic field per record in sunspot /solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I am using the dynamic_string in my product model to index a load of
user created dynamic fields.  This works great and gives me the
ablitiy in my view to show the following to allow the user to narrow
the results :

```
Color
----------
red
green
blue
etc...
```

The problem is that in some of these there are 2 or more options for a
product ie color => blue, red

When i try to add this into the color hash it just over rides the
first one, only letting me have one value for each field.

Is there a way to have multiple values per dynamic field per
product ?   If so please can you tell me how this can be achieved ?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the Solr [`schema.xml`](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml) that comes with Sunspot, I see the following declarations:

```
<!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
<dynamicField name="*_ds" stored="true" type="date" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
<!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
<dynamicField name="*_dms" stored="true" type="date" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

The dynamic string field (`_ds`) does not support multiple values, but there seems to be a dynamic multi string (`_dms`). I don't know Sunspot well enough to tell you how this fiels is actually called but it should be easy to find out.